# STL algorithm to delete all the objects in a container?

Tags: c++, boost, stl, stl-algorithm, boost-ptr-container

Is there a STL utility/algorithm to do `delete *the_object_iterator;` on all the objects? So that I can `clear()` safely? The STL container is a `set` and the objects are pointers to C++ classes created with `new`.

Boost seems to be the best solution. My goal was to avoid copy-construction on noncopyable classes.

Comment: Consider using Boost.PointerContainer instead http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/991335/how-to-erase-delete-pointers-to-objects-stored-in-a-vector

Comment: @Dabbler that's not a one-liner built-in

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to hold pointers in a container, because if the container is destroyed accidentally (via an exception for example) you won't get the opportunity to clean up properly.

Comment: ... to hold raw (dumb) pointers. It's OK to hold smart pointers. A common pattern, in fact.

Comment: @MSalters Boost.PointerContainer is the best solution. Smart pointers are dumb to me. ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no standard algorithm to delete all objects. However, you can build up one easily:

```
template< typename T > invoke_delete( T* ptr ){ delete ptr; }

std::for_each( set.begin(), set.end(), &invoke_delete< set_value_type > );
```

Comment: Or `std::for_each(set.begin(), set.end(), [](T* p){delete p;})` (not a template; substitute T yourself).

Comment: @MSalters: Indeed, but that's C++11 and I happen to know the OP is working with VC++9.

Answer (score 16):

Use a smart pointer to hold the class pointers

```
std::set<std::unique_ptr<MyClass> > mySet;
```

Comment: didn't notice that was in the std:: namespace

Comment: @unixman83: `unique_ptr` is new in C++11. If you don't have it in your compiler yet, you can use `boost::shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 7):

Boost pointer containers are the way to go.

Not only do they store the dynamically allocated objects. But the objects are accessible as references which makes using the standard algorithms on the the object that much easier.

```
boost::ptr_set<MyClass>   setData;

setData.insert(new MyClass);
```