# Safely erasing from vector of pointers

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

Ok, this is probably pretty basic, but I've never done it before.

I have a vector of `Particle`s, and when they leave the visible screen, I want to erase them. I looked up the erase-remove idiom, but I don't know how to make that work, because I also need to delete the `Particle` instances. I tried with backwards iteration, without success:

```
for ( std::vector<Particle*>::reverse_iterator rit = particles.rbegin(); rit != particles.rend(); ++rit )
{
    if ( IsOffScreen((*rit)->pos) )
    {
        delete (*rit.base());
        particles.erase(rit.base());
    }
}
```

At runtime crash, Visual Studio says `"iterator cannot be decremented"`. What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way?

Comment: You mustn't say `++rit` when `rit` isn't a valid iterator.

Comment: You will find the return value of [`std::vector<T>::erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) particularly helpful in solving your issue, as it should be become the new iterator value rather than incrementing/decrementing the exiting one in the event of an erasure.

Comment: Make this with indexes in reverse order.

Comment: If you used smart pointers, you could use the erase-remove idiom and stop worrying about leaks.

Comment: @syam Yes I might do that, but I wanted to measure performance with a lot of particles before, and compare smart pointers vs raw pointers.

Comment: @Innkeeper `unique_ptr` has **zero** overhead compared to raw pointers, it's just template magic. `shared_ptr` is another story, of course, but since your vector obviously owns the particles, `unique_ptr` would be appropriate here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to erase & delete pointers to objects stored in a vector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/991335/how-to-erase-delete-pointers-to-objects-stored-in-a-vector)

Comment: @syam Thank you, I did not know that. I'll probably use that then!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
for (std::vector<Particle*>::iterator it = particles.begin(); it != particles.end(); ++it) {
    if (IsOffScreen((*it)->pos)) {
        delete *it;
        *it = NULL;
    }
}
particles.erase(std::remove(particles.begin(), particles.end(), NULL), particles.end());
```

There are various other options - you could actually delete them in the predicate, for example, since IIRC it's guaranteed to be run exactly once on each item.

You do need to be careful with `remove` and `remove_if` for this kind of thing, since the removed objects are left in undefined state, so it's not possible to `remove` them and delete afterwards (you can use `std::partition` for that, but it's slower).

Comment: This yields `error C2446: '==' : no conversion from 'const int' to 'Particle *'` in `std::algorithm`.

Comment: Maybe it wants `(Particle*)NULL`?

Comment: One can use std::remove_if with a predicate that modifies the element to be removed ;)

Comment: @Peter yes, that was it.